# Separating frontend(html) and backend(flask). Changes in project structure

Tags: api, flask, model-view-controller, backend

https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/13-Deployment-Linode

I followed a tutorial on youtube and the code is as above.
I'm trying to separate the frontend (currently in html, which i will convert to react js later) and the backend. I do not want to render the html files through the server side. Was hoping to make different project for client side and server side for members to work on. I have read about the mvc project structure but I'm unable to decide which files i need to change or what to exactly look for when I google. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I have also taken that course on youtube. But your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to do?  You said `I do not want to render the html files through the server side` I don't think it is possible

Comment: @Aditya I suppose that he wants to serve the frontend from something like Nginx instead of from a python server like gunicorn

Comment: Instead of rendering html pages from flask i want to return json data to the frontend developr. Also divide the project under models and controllers